# Quotes printing text from MySQL

Tags: php, html-entities

When I display a text from the mysql commentaries field I use the following function in php:

```
nl2br(html_entity_decode($comment['message']))
```

and when inserted in the database in the query I use:

```
htmlentities($_POST['message'])
```

The question is that when I write a sentence like: "Hello" and displayed it shows: \"Hello\"

How can I avoid this?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

Here is the insert:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO db.tablon (pID, userID, message, date_inserted, answer)
                VALUES (:proyectoID, :userID, :mensaje, NOW(), :respuesta_mensaje_id)";
    $stmt  = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userID',     $userID,                    PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':proyectoID', $_POST['pID'],              PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':mensaje',    htmlentities($_POST['respuesta_tablon']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':respuesta_mensaje_id',   $_POST['mID'],  PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $res = $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Your server must have magic quotes enabled. Disable that setting. http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

Comment: I have read the link and indicates that from PHP 5.4 that function has been removed, and I use PHP 5.4.3

Comment: Can you post the code you are using for the insert?

Comment: Okay, you're binding I thought it might have been an attempt at sanitizing data. I've never seen this behavior outside of magic quotes or when written by a developer.

Comment: Even If I remove the htmlentities function, the result is the same. Curious!

Answer (score 0):

Escape them for mysql

```
$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['message']);

mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['message']);
```